# Locations in GPS radius around phone location

Tags: ios5, gps, geolocation, core-location

I have some addresses with gps data in my database. Now i want to use them in my iOS app, to make a lookup which of these addresses are in a radius of 30km from the phone location.
How can i do this?

Comment: At this time, i have only a idea to do this. But i dont think, that it is the best. The idea was to send the phone coordinates to my server. The server should check every address with Google an my coordinates. That's not the best way, i think.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.
You can use the CLLocation Framework with this function.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:

Also you can do this with MySQL.
Look at this page, for more information.
http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL